# I'm trying to complete the Django website tutorial, following the youtube tutorial - and at the beginning I have this "error"

Tags: python, django, python-venv

The tutorial writes in `source env/bin/activate`

When I write it in this is what comes out:

> (venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\FirstProject>source env/bin/activate
>   'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

He uses a mac and I use Windows 10, do I need a different line of code?

Comment: It's a relative path to `activate` script - so you can try to finding it on your drive. Also prefix `(venv)` hints that you're already "inside" virtual env (it's been activated).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pycharm you already get virtualenv created but if u are using vs code or any other editor then you should try this

```
pip install pipenv
create a virtual env: virtualenv .
to activate the virtualenv: 
windows:  .\Scripts\activate
linux or mac:  ./bin/activate
```

Comment: I am using Pycharm, so I should just move on as if it's already built in?

Comment: The virtual environment should be activated when you open Pycharm.

Comment: ya if you only want to create a virtual env then go on it's already created in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

just run: `env\Scripts\activate`. You do not need to use `source` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

don't use source, instead just type in `your_env_name\Scripts\activate.bat`

Remember to use backward slashes.